# Creating An In-Game Web Browser on iPhone

Tags: iphone, browser

In my game, I'd like to have a kinda of "message of the day" feature. Basically, when I hit the "message of the day" button in themain menu, it would open up a browser view in-game. When the user is done, he taps a "close" button and the view disappears, returning him to the game menu.

So, is it possible to dynamically create a browser view? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for UIWebView :-)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html